# reduce printing size

Tags: printing

I need to print a shipping label that's in the form of a PDF.  The problem is that it's too large for the package so it has to be reduced in size.  It's easy to reduce the size of the visual image, but that doesn't seem to affect the size of the printed page.  I've tried both Ocular and qpdfview but wasn't able to get them to do this. How can I reduce that size?

Answer (score 0):

I get the Scale option to downscale the printed output

[image]

...and also "Shrink to printable area"

[image]

PS: This is on Mate 18.04, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also print multiple copies of the same file per page. Like four on one page which will greatly reduce the size of the print out.[image: Ubuntu print dialog showing four pages per page]